# How to create Carousel (with auto Slide) using custom element directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a Carousel which is supposed to slide automatically in a particular time interval. Below is my code. For reference: [onehungrymind](http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/).

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="SampleApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Carousel</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <custom-carousel></custom-carousel>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="carousel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**carouselView.html**

```html
<div class="container slider">
    <img ng-repeat="slide in slides" class="slide slide-animation nonDraggableImage"
         ng-swipe-right="nextSlide()" ng-swipe-left="prevSlide()"
         ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.image}}"/>

    <a class="arrow prev" href="#" ng-click="nextSlide()"></a>
    <a class="arrow next" href="#" ng-click="prevSlide()"></a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="dot" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
                    <a href="#" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}"
                       ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index);">{{slide.description}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**carousel.js**

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module('SampleApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']);
sampleApp.directive('customCarousel', function(){
 
 var ctrl = function($scope){
  $scope.slides = [ 
            {image: 'images/img1.jpg', description: 'Image 00'}, 
            {image: 'images/img2.jpg', description: 'Image 01'}, 
            {image: 'images/img3.jpg', description: 'Image 02'}, 
            {image: 'images/img4.jpg', description: 'Image 03'}, 
            {image: 'images/img5.jpg', description: 'Image 04'} 
  ]; 
  $scope.direction = 'left';
        $scope.currentIndex = 0;

        $scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
            $scope.direction = (index > $scope.currentIndex) ? 'left' : 'right';
            $scope.currentIndex = index;
        };

        $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
            return $scope.currentIndex === index;
        };

        $scope.prevSlide = function () {
            $scope.direction = 'left';
            $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
        };

        $scope.nextSlide = function () {
            $scope.direction = 'right';
            $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex > 0) ? --$scope.currentIndex : $scope.slides.length - 1;
        };
  
  //$interval($scope.prevSlide(), 2000);
 }
 return {
  restrict:'E',
  controller:ctrl,
  templateUrl:'carouselView.html'
 };
}).animation('.slide-animation', function () {
        return {
            addClass: function (element, className, done) {
                if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                    TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {left: -element.parent().width(), onComplete: done });
                }
                else {
                    done();
                }
            },
            removeClass: function (element, className, done) {
                if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                    element.removeClass('ng-hide');

                    TweenMax.set(element, { left: element.parent().width() });
                    TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {left: 0, onComplete: done });
                }
                else {
                    done();
                }
            }
        };
});
```

Everything is working fine except auto slide. I did attempt to call prevSlide() and nextSlide() from a $interval service (commented line), But didn't work. Probably I am not injecting $interval service properly.

```js
sampleApp.directive('customCarousel', ['$interval', function($interval){
  //code
}]);
```

**Output Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use angular bootstrap directives?
[check here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
Its already created there

Comment: @Maverick, thanks for quick response. Actually I have to create Carousel using a custom directive though It can be created using angula-ui. Do you have any idea how can we do it this way?